# ¿Cómo puedo cargar el fontawesome para laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, font-awesome

Tengo el archivo pero al hacer el cambio no lo coge, lo descargué de la pagina de fontawesome y copié el archivo css a mi carpeta `publi/css` pero no toma los iconos. Ya sé que las lineas cambian a fas,far.. pero no parece ser por eso.

P.D no me carga tampoco por consola y ya descargué el ultimo npm, el notjs que tenia antes era version 2 desde el 2016 que no lo usaba, pero al parecer tampoco era eso.

[image: carpeta public]

Cambié el texto de font-awesome a fontawesome pero no reconoce los iconos, carga solo cuadrados.

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/font-awesome.css')}}">
```

[image: Algo parece faltar en el archivo si alguien sabe que es agradeceria su respuesta]

P.D. también cargué el archivo .js y lo intente relacionar por script pero tampoco funcionó.

Comment: buenas, vi la edición que dieron como sugerencias, pero no encontre donde aceptarla, por lo cual,  me toco rechazarla para continuar

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo del HTML completo? Qué ícono estás tratando de cargar?

Comment: Ya decide trabajar con la versión de fontawesome que funciona imo thanks